# I'm getting an "iPhone Transfer Cannot Be Completed" message claiming my new phone doesn't have enough storage. It does

Tags: iphone, data-transfer, setup

I have a shiny new iPhone 12 Pro. It has 128 GB of storage.

I am transferring data (or trying to), from my old and busted iPhone X. It has 256 GB of storage, but I'm only using 60 GB of that space.

The data transfer starts as normal, but fails after about 10 minutes with an error that there is insufficient space on the new phone to take data over from the old phone. I even freed up about 20 GB, just to see if that would make a difference but it didn't.

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Are you transferring it directly from phone to phone? Have you tried backing up the old phone to your computer and then restoring to the new one?

Comment: @SteveChambers I've tried both! Phone to Phone says insufficient storage. From my Mac, it just silently fails.

Comment: It may be time to try backing it up with iMazing or iExplore (I think at least one offers a trial version that will do that for free) and then restoring it to the new phone. Understand that your *busted* iPhone may be so busted that it will *always* fail any attempt at backing it up.

Comment: It's not actually busted as in broken. It's just a colloquialism. It functions perfectly fine, it's just... my backups are weirdly large.

Comment: So if iTunes backups fail and you need a backup then you will likely have to go to a 3rd-party utility. At least one is free and allows you to backup without paying for it. Sounds like that's your best next step.